# How to get photo_reference of a photo using Google Places API in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-places-api

I am trying to get the place details through Google Autocomplete in Angular.

My code is:

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchBar');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
});
```

When I print `place` using `console.log()`, I do not get `photo_reference` field in `photos` array as suggested [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search)

I am only getting the following in the `photos` array

```
"photos": [{
     "height": 1198,
     "html_attributions": [
                ... something ...
            ],
     "width": 1600
 },...]
```

Whereas, If I call the same API using CURL or POSTMAN, I do get the `photo_reference` field.

```
"photos": [{
      "height": 364,
      "html_attributions": [
                   ... something ...
      ],
       "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAAZbczldylJ55Yk8EsT6SgRMstEc2-aZIBJreHNmjKQh_2HU5rAWE3y1FKD3gyr5bUo9lx-UD-jz-CseqRv1l88lQhjZdFXTBOWyKegbb_xX9VnWSRs6Dlkp0CpngP1gtzEhDRByCLpQYQFrmmN-l6gmCvGhR0-JtgWPXvhv_yumVbJiGqfP-ArQ",
      "width": 550
 },....]
```

How do I get the `photo_reference`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am also getting same issue.In photo array i am not getting photo reference.Please help me if you found any solution for it.It would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Google Autocomplete doesn't provide `photo_reference` attribute.

But as Salty Egg mentioned, you can call:

```
place.photos[0].getUrl({'maxWidth': 500, 'maxHeight': 500})
```

wich will return back a photo URL like:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/PhotoService.GetPhoto?1sCmRaAAAAaMqJfssQ7GtvlNWHquUob3f4f_w7d3SlDT0u84-m4ZmBW1rK5iu8XrvK1Thz6plwOsaq9yt-p9gAPfHBDDf6xuIU71WJTZ8BdyWxJIOsj836Rfk1bghIcgAi_L-ffoBzEhDXy7_TigSRZnkP7a6laSvnGhTLzJ34PDMlvi4nuTAZVsQO9iqcXw&3u1000&4u667&5m1&2e1&callback=none&key=YOUR_API_KEY&token=SOME_TOKEN

where

CmRaAAAAaMqJfssQ7GtvlNWHquUob3f4f_w7d3SlDT0u84-m4ZmBW1rK5iu8XrvK1Thz6plwOsaq9yt-p9gAPfHBDDf6xuIU71WJTZ8BdyWxJIOsj836Rfk1bghIcgAi_L-ffoBzEhDXy7_TigSRZnkP7a6laSvnGhTLzJ34PDMlvi4nuTAZVsQO9iqcXw&3u1000&4u667&5m1&2e1

is `photo_reference`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you already found solution or not. But I find a way to get the photo url.

[image: There is a <code>getUrl</code> function inside photo object]

Then, you can call:

```
place.photos[0].getUrl({'maxWidth': 500, 'maxHeight': 500})
```

Finally, we can have the url as something like: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMghp6IzB9xG019r-1mo8wgBmuKa3_oVadVEu7S=w500-h500-k"

Comment: Sorry, I failed to answer your real question `How to get photo_reference`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17301351)

Comment: Thank you, @wscourge. I would like to do that if I could, but that time, my reputation is too low to leave a comment below the post. Sorry for this. But I just try to help